# initialization new map and set in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, init

Hi i am doing my homeworks and i have a problem.

I need diferents maps and set in the application and i want reuse some variables.
I have this global variables

`map<char,set<char> > IAF; //I Am Father
map<char,int> NBM; //Number Before Me
set<char> WCR; //Who can run`

and every time in the main i need reset this variables.

I have done two things:

`IAF =  new map<char,set<char> >;`

and

`IAF =  map<char,set<char> >;`

But any has run.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
IAF.clear()
NBM.clear()
WCR.clear()
```

(Edit: references to the spec and caveats)

- [map::clear()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear)
- [set::clear()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/clear)

Note that if you're storing pointers, `clear()` will remove the pointers, but **it will not delete** the memory pointed to by the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

```
map<char,set<char> > IAF;
```

This is a definition of variable. This is not a pointer. If you want to do some kind of initialization you can use one of [supported methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), e.g:

```
std::copy( differentContainer.begin(), differentContainer.end(), IAF.begin());
```

or

```
while( ...) {
    IAF.insert( ...);
    // or
    IAF[ key] = value;
}
```

To delete the content of map you can do (this will not automatically delete memory pointed to by pointer in map - if you store pointers, use a smart pointers then):

```
IAF.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers which are fairly clear. The `new` keyword, that you used at some point, is to allocate memory for a pointer.

```
map<char, set<char> > *IAF = new map<char, set<char> >;
//...
// free the memory
delete IAF;
```

Check the [Dynamic memory allocation](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/) for more information and to understand **when** and **how** to use pointers.

Also, using

```
IAF =  map<char,set<char> >;
```

Is incorrect. The `map<char, set<char> >` is a class name (combined with templates generic programming, see the answer to [What is the meaning of "generic programming" in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862378/what-is-the-meaning-of-generic-programming-in-c) ) and hence you cannot assign it to a variable in this way. What you want to do is to call the constructor that will return an instance of that class:

IAF = map >();

However, doing it this way is not efficient at all. It creates a temporary object, destroys `IAF`, copies the temporary, and then destroys the temporary (unless you are using C++11 and in this case you use `move`, but still...). So, it's better to use the `clear()` as stated by the other answers.